# Django logging issue on IIS

Tags: python, django, logging, iis

I'm new to Django and the IIS server. I have a web server deployed with IIS, and I'm encountering an issue with the code. I'd like to try fixing it on my own, but I don't have a console (like in development mode) to show me what's going on. So, I started trying the logging functions in settings.py. Here's my configuration

```
FORMATTERS = ({"verbose": 
              {"format": "{levelname} {asctime:s} {name} {threadName} {thread:d} {module} {filename} {lineno:d} {name} {funcName} {process:d} {message}",
               "style": "{",},
               "simple": {
                          "format": "{levelname} {asctime:s} {name} {module} {filename} {lineno:d} {funcName} {message}",
                          "style": "{",
                          },
               },
              )
```

```
HANDLERS = {"console_handler": 
            {"class": "logging.StreamHandler",
             "formatter": "simple","level": "DEBUG"},
             "info_handler": 
                {"class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
                 "filename": f"{BASE_DIR}/logs/blogthedata_info.log",
                 "mode": "a",
                 "encoding": "utf-8",
                 "formatter": "verbose",
                 "level": "INFO",
                 "backupCount": 5,
                 "maxBytes": 1024 * 1024 * 5,  # 5 MB},
                 "error_handler": 
                    {"class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
                     "filename": f"{BASE_DIR}/logs/blogthedata_error.log",
                     "mode": "a",
                     "formatter": "verbose",
                     "level": "WARNING",
                     "backupCount": 5,
                     "maxBytes": 1024 * 1024 * 5,  # 5 MB
                    },
            }
           }
```

```
LOGGERS = ({"django": 
           {
            "handlers": ["console_handler", "info_handler"],
            "level": "INFO",},
            "django.request": 
             {
              "handlers": ["error_handler"],
              "level": "INFO",
              "propagate": True,
             },
            "django.template": 
             {
              "handlers": ["error_handler"],
              "level": "DEBUG",
              "propagate": True,
             },
            "django.server": 
             {
              "handlers": ["error_handler"],
              "level": "INFO",
              "propagate": True,
             },
            }, 
           )
```

```
LOGGING = {
           "version": 1,
           "disable_existing_loggers":False,
           "formatters": FORMATTERS[0],
           "handlers": HANDLERS,
           "loggers": LOGGERS[0],
          }
```

taken from this explanation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_EkU56KdJg)

This code generates 4 files: blogthedata_detailed.log blogthedata_error.log blogthedata_info.log

```
the detailed.log contains this:INFO 2023-08-25 11:53:47,710 Thread-1 (process_request_thread) 8792 basehttp basehttp.py 212 django.server log_message 12856 "GET /static/js/login_script.js HTTP/1.1" 200 751INFO 2023-08-25 11:53:47,780 Thread-2 (process_request_thread) 20080 basehttp basehttp.py 212 django.server log_message 12856 "GET /static/js/jQuery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 304662INFO 2023-08-25 11:53:47,792 Thread-2 (process_request_thread) 20080 basehttp basehttp.py 212 django.server log_message 12856 "GET /static/images/IRS.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5182INFO 2023-08-25 11:53:47,927 Thread-2 (process_request_thread) 20080 basehttp basehttp.py 212 django.server log_message 12856 "GET /static/images/bg.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5691309INFO 2023-08-25 11:53:50,260 Thread-2 (process_request_thread) 20080 basehttp basehttp.py 212 django.server log_message 12856 "POST /dm/send_login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 31INFO 2023-08-25 11:53:50,287 Thread-2 (process_request_thread) 20080 basehttp basehttp.py 212 django.server log_message 12856 "GET /dm/barcode/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1485INFO 2023-08-25 11:53:50,324 Thread-2 (process_request_thread) 20080 basehttp basehttp.py 212 django.server log_message 12856 "GET /static/css/style_barcode.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2212INFO 2023-08-25 11:53:50,328 Thread-1 (process_request_thread) 8792 basehttp basehttp.py 212 django.server log_message 12856 "GET /static/images/goback.png HTTP/1.1" 200 519INFO 2023-08-25 11:53:50,389 Thread-2 (process_request_thread) 20080 basehttp basehttp.py 212 django.server log_message 12856 "GET /static/js/barcode_script.js HTTP/1.1" 200 4312
```

And the other 3 files are empty

How can I see the print statements I insert into the code, and especially the debug error when a certain line of code isn't functioning properly?

Comment: In your current configuration, the django logger is at level INFO, which means it will only catch messages of level INFO or higher. If you want to capture DEBUG level messages (which include your print statements and more detailed debug information), you need to adjust the logger's level to DEBUG.